# How to download first X bytes of a file in userscript?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'm trying to download first 500kb of a ~10mb file with a Tampermonkey script. What I've tried already is several variations of:

```
// random 1mb text for testing
var url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/khaykov/a6105154becce4c0530da38e723c2330/raw/41ab415ac41c93a198f7da5b47d604956157c5c3/gistfile1.txt";

var request = new Object();
request.abort = GM_xmlhttpRequest({
  method: "GET",
  url: url,
  responseType: 'arraybuffer',
  onerror: function (error) {console.log(error);},
  onload: function(args) { console.log(args.response.length); /* this part works */ },
  onprogress: function(args) { if (args.loaded > 100000) { request.abort(); /* throws "request.abort is not a function" */ } }
});
```

How do I get the abort function returned by `GM_xmlhttpRequest()` to be callable from the onprogress callback? Or is there a better way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: It should be `var request = GM_xmlhttpRequest(.......`

Comment: Are the docs wrong? It says `Returns an object with the following property:
abort - function to be called to cancel this request`

Comment: Oh. I misread it! Thought it returned the function itself.

Comment: OK it seems it doesn't really cancel the download. I ended up using `headers: {"Range": "bytes=0-500000"}` instead.